# Changing encoding of layers in Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet in R to make an interactive map.

Data I'm using was created using QGIS with Windows-1250 encoding (it's a non-English language). The layers were then exported as geoJSON which only allows UTF-8 encoding and when displaying the features on the map some characters are, of course, displayed wrong.

Is there a way of displaying the encoding properly? Trying to manually change the data results in:

> Error: unexpected symbol in x' (x is the wrongly encoded data point I tried to rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying the vector format of the data *before* being exported - this is more important than the tool used to create that data.

*Assuming* that the data is in shapefiles, you can use the approach from the question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/44057 , and rely on `ogr2ogr` to both convert to GeoJSON and handle character encoding.

Comment: Yes, it was a shapefile. I tried the ogr2ogr only to fail but in the end I managed to do it using 
`variable= readOGR(dsn='~/shapefile-name.shp', 
                    layer='layer-name', 
                    encoding='windows1250') %>%
  geojson_json() %>%
  geojson_write(file='~/output-name.geojson', encoding='windows1250')`

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea how to format this properly.